# Thead concurrency in sqlite using static functions

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

What is the right way to manage SQLiteConnection to avoid DatabaseConnectionException?

I've tried putting  some flags in the sqliteconnection constructor and using the Using statement, but it does not seem to work

```
public class BaseDao
{
    //[...] some static functions

    static string Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mysqlite.db3");

    /// <summary>
    /// Searches all records of the specified type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the Type to search</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Returns a list of all records of the specified type</returns>
    public static List<T> GetItems<T>() where T : BaseEntity, new()
    {
        List<T> items;

        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex, true))
        {
            try
            {
                items = connection.Query<T>("SELECT * FROM " + typeof(T).Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connection.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

(these functions are not called by the UI Thread.)

Comment: Why not just make it a singleton with locks?

Comment: What is the full exception message?

Comment: Perhaps the right question is: "is there any correct way to do that using static functions?"

Comment: I don't know what effect those flags on the constructor have but your code looks thread safe to me. I'm not convinced your problem is thread concurrency.

Comment: Again, I don't know the implementation of `SQLiteConnection` but you don't need to close it in a `finally` block if it is declared in a `using`. What line throws the exception?

Comment: it's rare but i'm getting " System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException Message: database is locked "